# VBA - Excel - Finding the cell location of a userform TextBox populated by a for i loop?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, excel-2010, userform

**What do I need to know?**

How do I get the location of the data that a textbox is displaying? How do I know where it is?

**What am I doing?**

I have some code that loops through i and assigns it a value then pulls the cell value from a sheet based on i....so (i, 2) is simply: Row i from Column 2. This is then displayed in a userform Textbox.

**What I want to do?**

Add a dbl_click event, so that someone can double click on the textbox and be sent to the sheet/row/column that is being displayed.  I have no issue creating the dbl_click event, but my problem appears to be how to get the cell location being displayed?

If it is relevant, this is my code for the loop:

```
Dim code as String
code = search.Value

For i = 2 To LastRow
            
If Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Value = code Then
     
ssn1.Text = Sheet1.name
hb11.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Value
End If
Next i
```

This is a snippet, as this goes on for awhile, hb11 runs though to hb37 - didn't see any reason to paste it all here.

The problem is, that the loop continues through, across multiple sheets as well, finding all examples of "code" so i keeps changing, after it has written the data to the TextBox - so I can't rely on (i, 9) from the loop.

I have gotten this far in terms of code:

```
Sub bt11_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   
    If hb11.Value <> ("") Then

    Application.Goto Reference:=Sheet1.Range(hb11)
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

However this appears to be relying on the value of hb11, rather than the cell location.

I know this is a dumb question, I know, but I just can't seem to find the answer?

I get the feeling that it lies in:

```
Dim cell as Range
```

Then:

```
Set cell = hb11.something
```

But I have been through the list, cell/range gives a mismatch, and don't actually exist in the list.  There is no 'linked cell' as I thought that might do it...

I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Profit from using the `.Tag` property**

I'm assuming each of your 27 textboxes refers to exactly one source range address which consists of sheetname, row and column (or column character).

If so you can profit from assigning a combined reference string (e.g. `"Sheet22" & "," & i & "," & 9`) to a textbox'es  ►`.Tag` property during the initializing loop, e.g. in a comma separated way like perhaps

```
    hb11.Tag = "Sheet22,17,9"      ' << i.e. sheet name, row 17, column 9
```

I think it'll be easy to get all data from there:

```
    Dim src: src = split(hb11,",") 
    Application.Goto Reference:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(src(0)).Range(Cells(Val(src(1)), Val(src(2))).Address), Scroll:=True
```

Comment: Thanks T.M., but I can't get that to work, it says "Subscript out of range".  I tried tinkering but couldn't get it to work, with one error or another.  Also, I am surprised there isn't an easier way?

Comment: Several hours later, I have worked out this.

if I insert

    Dim ac as Range
    Dim addy as String
    Dim code as String
    code = search.Value
    
    For i = 2 To LastRow
                
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Value = code Then
         
    ssn1.Text = Sheet1.name
    hb11.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Value
    Set ac = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9)
    End If
    Next i
    
    addy = ac.Address(ReferenceSyle:=xlR1C1)

    End Sub


addy now equals R2C9 which is the format that you need for Application.Goto

As soon as I leave the sub, I lose the value of addy!!

Comment: It lies in the nature of a variable declared in a procedure that it gets lost when leaving the sub. - a) Simply add the code line `hb11.Tag = ssn1.Text & "," & addy` to your sub (of course you can define `*xlR1C1*` ReferenceStyle, too) and b) refer to the reference *stored* in the ►`.Tag` property via `Application.Goto Reference:= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(src(0)).Range(src(1)), Scroll:=True` in a similar way as shown above (after splitting via `Dim src: src = split(hb11, ",")`

Answer (score 0):

Too many hours later, I have worked this out.

Thanks to T.M. for the idea about re-writing the data out of a stored place.

Outside of any sub, I created a String - right at the top.

```
Dim ac1 As String
```

Inside my loop, I simply gave ac1 the value of i,

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
            
If Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Value = code Then
     
ssn1.Text = Sheet1.name
hb11.Text = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Value
ac1 = i
End If
Next i
```

This works, because you only run through this loop, IF code exists, since the list is unique, code only exists once.  So you only go into the loop once, and when you do, i = the row.

Then using T.M.'s idea, I wrote out:

```
Application.Goto Reference:=Sheet1.Range("A" & ac1)
```

This is a range reference that Goto can handle.

The advantage of this method is, because I am searching multiple sheets with multiple Textboxes, I only need ac1 for a whole sheets worth of Textboxes.

Hope this helps someone in the future.